# Full Text Not Returning The Expected Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I am really baffled at this current problem we are having.

I have never seen this happen before..and have no clue why it is doing so.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.MY_ID , MY_NAME
FROM MYTABLE p
WHERE CONTAINS( (p.MY_NAME), '"nn11"' );
```

the my_name column is full text indexed and a `varchar(100)`

- with `nn11` - I get 15 results all containing `11` in it, but no `nn` characters in name...
- with `n11` - I get 0 results
- with `11` I get the same 15 results as with `nn11`

Problem is, there are no `n` characters anywhere in the results, so technically I should be getting 0 results on all counts, but the fact I get results some of the time make no sense to me...

Do I need to rebuild the index? is it possible it is corrupted?

thanks in advance

here is the additonal info

These are the results i am getting at the moment.... for both nn11 and 11 but 0 results for n11...

```
MYID    MYNAME
------- ------- 
18546   11
18693   11
18747   11
18781   11
18799   11
18800   11
18873   11
18958   11
18989   11
18993   11
19069   11
19122   11
19124   11-B
19186   11-A
19407   11-A
```

and the results for each run:

```
nn11 - 0x006E006E00310031  1 0 1 Exact Match    nn11    0   nn11
n11 -  0x006E00310031      1 0 1 Exact Match    n11     0   n11
11-    0x00310031          1 0 1 Exact Match    11      0   11
       0x006E006E00310031  1 0 1 Exact Match    nn11    0   11
```

Comment: It would help if you show the actual data you expect to match, not just the search terms. And have you used [`sys.dm_fts_parser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) to examine how SQL Server is parsing your data?

Comment: I get the following results

Comment: i hate these comment boxes

Comment: This shouldn't matter, but you're performing an implicit conversion of `'"nn11"'` because the <contains_search_condition> is an Nvarchar and forces this conversion. Can you try putting an "N" in front, so `N'"nn11"'`? Like I said, I don't think this should matter, but I'm seeing weird behavior when performing my own conversions that do not align with the hex values you provided.

Comment: Please post a `CREATE TABLE` statement, some `INSERT`s to populate it with test data, your test query, and your `sys.dm_fts_parser` query. Your sample data is too difficult to read and there's no easy way for me to use it. If I had a complete test case that I could just copy and paste into SSMS and run immediately then I would be more inclined to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are actually stored in the FTI with an nn prefix, which explains why a search for nn11 returns the same result as for 11 but not n11. It seems there's no direct fix for this, but a workaround is described at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/8592ea09-fcfb-4fec-a3a4-5e03dedcee3a/